# "INSERT WHERE NOT EXIST" - working on local (5.6.35) but not on server (5.7.22) - No errors are shown

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following SQL Query/Statement:

```
INSERT INTO `tags` (`tag`) SELECT 'water' FROM tags WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM `tags` WHERE `tag`='water') LIMIT 1
```

The table structure has just 2 columns `(id, tag)`.

The SQL statements functionality is to receive a tag, in the case above it receives `water`, it checks if the tag already exists. If the tag already exists it should return 0 results. If it doesn't exist, it should create a new row with the tag.

Currently, it works only on my local MAMP server which runs MySQL version 5.6.35). I've tested on two other MySQL versions, 5.6.39-log and 5.7.22... and none of them seem to work.

The only thing in terms of errors that displays is before I run the query:
[image: Errors shown before]

However, running that does not give an error but rather a green box stating `0 rows inserted. (Query took 0.0014 seconds.)`

Has the syntax changed? If so, can someone point me to any documentation? I've been scouring the documentation all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insert seems to work as long as there's at least some other any row on the table. If the table is empty, the insert is not executed.

```
create table tags(id integer, tag varchar(255));
commit;

insert into tags (tag) values('xxxx');
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO `tags` (`tag`) SELECT 'water' FROM tags WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM `tags` WHERE `tag`='water') LIMIT 1;
COMMIT;

select * from tags
```

It returns 2 rows (xxxx and water) However, if I remove the INSERT xxxx, then nothing is inserted and thus nothing returned.

[See here.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gfQGP22L8jRjq6CnPGD4H/0) You can try with different versions of mysql. It seems to behabe the same way across all versions

I believe a simpler alternative youd be to use a `INSERT IGNORE` statement.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aDZpjz3K1L15bc69bUDkEz/0

```
insert ignore into tags  values(1,'xxxx');
insert ignore into tags  values(1,'xxxx');
insert ignore into tags  values(1,'xxxx');

insert ignore into tags  values(2,'water');
insert ignore into tags  values(2,'water');
insert ignore into tags  values(2,'water');
```

> If you use the IGNORE modifier, errors that occur while executing the
>   INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that
>   duplicates an  existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table
>   causes a duplicate-key  error and the statement is aborted. With
>   IGNORE, the row is discarded and  no error occurs. Ignored errors
>   generate warnings instead.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Comment: Hmm, super strange that it doesn't work on an empty table! But can confirm that was the issue. The `INSERT IGNORE` statement seems to just insert it as a new row regardless if it exists or not. I marked your answer as correct as it solved the issue in my question.

Comment: Yes, quite strange. While I found the root of the problem, I still cannot understand this design (perhaps a bug?). The INSERT IGNORE should 'work' (don't allow duplicates) as long as there's a primary and/or unique index on the table

Comment: Yeah, ill look into it. Thanks for your help.